# Step up voltage Transformer for more watt?

Tags: transformer, pulse, watts, trigger, current-transformer

Using generator in mountain or underground tunnel location, construction workers from portable generator gets maximum:

> AC Output: 220volt as 200 to 250watt

Now, they need to use a machine for construction activity, where there machine requires:

> AC Input: 220volt as 700watt

Now can they use following `pulse transformer` to supply `700watt` from there generator `200watt`?

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07B9J2RWQ/ref=sspa_dk_detail_1?psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07B9J2RWQ)

Please advise.

**EDIT:**

- Interleaved method.

[image]

Maybe a 700watt/hr Portable Lithium Battery with 500 watt Inverter connected to the generator. ([battery](https://www.ebay.com/itm/700watt-hr-Portable-Lithium-Battery-with-500-watt-Inverter-SOLAR-GENERATOR/272568383569?_trkparms=aid%3D777003%26algo%3DDISCL.MBE%26ao%3D2%26asc%3D44039%26meid%3D6314b55b4d1247ba8918bb1729ccc9d3%26pid%3D100012%26rk%3D9%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D263247425773%26itm%3D272568383569&_trksid=p2047675.c100012.m1985))

Comment: Supplying 700W from 200W generator? Trying to break the law of conservation of energy. Not possible. Period.

Comment: What you have illustrated is not a pulse transformer, it's an ordinary 110/230 transformer. Even a pulse transformer cannot increase average power, even though it can under certain circumstances increase the power by shortening a pulse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they can't.

The power supply, in this case the generator, must be able to supply enough power for it to work.

The transformer is not able to magically increase the power output of the original power source. Instead it will waste some in the process of transforming the voltage, so you get even less power out of it.

You need a bigger generator for this task.

---

The problem you are facing is the conservation of energy. And energy is power over time. So if you have a power supply with `200 W`, it will give you `200 J` per second of energy.

If you have a device using `700 W`, it will need `700 J` every second. No transformer in the world is able to give you `700 J` of energy every second when it is supplied only with `200 J` per second.

You could do an `interleaved mode`, so you could store energy for `4 seconds`, then you have `800 J`, then you can power your device for one second. That is the was those ultra high power lasers work - they would need more power than the grid is able to supply, so they are driven pulsed so there is time to charge.

In your case that is not possible.

---

As for your comment, please do not mix up the units. What is shown in that video is a step up from `3 V` to `500 V`. Only the voltage is increased. The product of voltage and current is the same (well minus losses).

So if that guy takes `500 W` from the `500 V (1 A)`, he needs to have `3 V` and `166 A (500 W)` at the input.

There is no way around energy conservation.

Comment: But pulse transformer is supposed to boost power? Can you please see this example where he produced massive watt from small input. Please correct me if my understanding is absolute wrong. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDZsBeYbDa4

Comment: Under certain conditions, a pulse transformer can output more power during a short output pulse than was used to 'charge' it during a long input pulse. However, the energy output for each pulse is always less than the energy input. This means the average power output is also always less than the average power input.

Comment: @YumYumYum I have updated my answer to make it maybe clearer.

Comment: Thank you very clear now. How do i resolve it? can i use some kind of battery(theory) to create that 5 seconds delay (interleaved mode)?